# extracting domain from URL and more

Tags: sql-server, extract

I am working in Microsoft SQL Server and want to strip a table of URLs down to the precise domains only (for joining purposes).

I have searched around here and am now able to get from http://www.starbucks.com/ to starbucks.com/ using:

```
RIGHT(web_domain, LEN(web_domain) - CHARINDEX('.', web_domain))
```

However, I am stuck and unable to get rid of that last slash...I really need to produce starbucks.com . Any ideas?

Please note that some of the domains naturally appear without the ending slash, so the solution must be able to allow domains that appear in the DB like this www.gap.com and become gap.com after running the above line of code to pass through as is.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    REPLACE(RIGHT(web_domain, LEN(web_domain) - CHARINDEX('.', web_domain)), '/', '')
```